# How to move reactjs components into seperate page when using CDN

Tags: reactjs, components, cdn

I'm learning ReactJS and I followed a tutorial that produced this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>React! React! React!</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router@2.4.0/umd/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>

</head>

 <body>

 <div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
 </div>

  <script type="text/babel">
var destination = document.querySelector("#container");

var { Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory, IndexLink, Link } = ReactRouter

var Home = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>HELLO</h2>
          <p>Cras facilisis urna ornare ex volutpat, et
          convallis erat elementum. Ut aliquam, ipsum vitae
          gravida suscipit, metus dui bibendum est, eget rhoncus nibh
          metus nec massa. Maecenas hendrerit laoreet augue
          nec molestie. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
          dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>

          <p>Duis a turpis sed lacus dapibus elementum sed eu lectus.</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
});

var Contact = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>GOT QUESTIONS?</h2>
          <p>The easiest thing to do is post on
          our
          </p>
        </div>
      );
    }
});

var Stuff = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>STUFF</h2>
          <p>Mauris sem velit, vehicula eget sodales vitae,
          rhoncus eget sapien:</p>
          <ol>
            <li>Nulla pulvinar diam</li>
            <li>Facilisis bibendum</li>
            <li>Vestibulum vulputate</li>
            <li>Eget erat</li>
            <li>Id porttitor</li>
          </ol>
        </div>
      );
    }
});

var FourOhFour = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>NOPE</h2>
          <p>This page is missing. Maybe it never existed.
          Maybe we never existed. What if nothing is real?</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
});


var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
        <ul className="header">
          <li><IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</IndexLink></li>
          <li><Link to="/stuff" activeClassName="active">Stuff</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/contact" activeClassName="active">Contact</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <div className="content">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="stuff" component={Stuff} />
      <Route path="contact" component={Contact} />
      <Route path='*' component={FourOhFour} />
    </Route>

  </Router>
), destination);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My question is how can I extract these components out into other pages? I've tried making a component like:

```
var React = require('react');

var Stuff = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>MORE STUFF!!!!</h2>
      <p>Mauris sem velit, vehicula eget sodales vitae,
      rhoncus eget sapien:</p>
      <ol>
        <li>Nulla pulvinar diam</li>
        <li>Facilisis bibendum</li>
        <li>Vestibulum vulputate</li>
        <li>Eget erat</li>
        <li>Id porttitor</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}
});

module.exports = Stuff;
```

Then in my main file I try:

```
import Stuff from './stuff.jsx';
```

But I just get this error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need `webpack` to transpile you components written in JSX to JS. Then you can import react like

```
import React from 'react';
```

instead of using `require`.

Sample webpack file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports ={

    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    devtool: "inline-sourcemap",
    entry: "./js/client.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015','stage-0'],
                    plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname+ "/src",
        filename: "client.min.js"
    }
}
```

[Webpack tutorial link](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack):